# upload a file to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

I am working on this project that allow users to upload a file to a firebase storage from their local computer.the user choose file or image to upload to firebase storage or firestore, a message is display if successful.

Below is the code i have written to achieve the task, but it is returning error, saying .put is not a function.

```
const handleUpload = () => {
    setUploading(true);
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`)
      .put(file)
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot);
        storageRef("files")
          .child(file.name)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            db.collection("myFiles").add({
              timestamp: db.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              caption: file.name,
              fileUrl: url,
              size: snapshot.bytesTransferred,
            });
            setUploading(false);
            setOpen(false);
            setFile(null);
          });
        storageRef("files")
          .child(file.name)
          .getMetadata()
          .then((meta) => {
            console.log(meta.size);
          });
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you call a [function called `ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#ref), it seems that you're using the modular API syntax to access Cloud Storage through Firebase. In that syntax, many API calls are top-level functions that you import explicitly and then call similar to how you call `ref`.

The top-level functions for uploading data in the modular API are `uploadBytes` and `uploadString`. I recommend checking out [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#web-modular-api_1) for an example of them.

Since the rest of your code is using the more traditional namespaced API that Firebase also supports, I recommend also reading the guide on [upgrading to the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade), and specifically focus on the section on [using the `compat` libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_compat), which might actually allow you to get your code working with a smaller change.